# Powershell showing only 0 values for available cipher suite

Tags: windows, ssl, powershell, azure

I have multiple VMs within the azure cloud. All of them, except one, are unable to connect to certain services using SSL with the message

> Invoke-Webrequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I already tried all suggested solutions from setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to messing with registry settings.

Now I noticed that the cipher suites on the servers are very different.

Not working:

```
KeyType               : 0
Certificate           :
MaximumExchangeLength : 0
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              :
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  :
CipherBlockLength     : 0
CipherLength          : 0
BaseCipherSuite       : 0
CipherSuite           : 0
Cipher                :
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Protocols             : {}
```

Working

```
KeyType               : 0
Certificate           : RSA
MaximumExchangeLength : 65536
MinimumExchangeLength : 0
Exchange              : ECDH
HashLength            : 0
Hash                  :
CipherBlockLength     : 16
CipherLength          : 128
BaseCipherSuite       : 49199
CipherSuite           : 49199
Cipher                : AES
Name                  : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Protocols             : {771, 65277}
```

How is this possible and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check your certificate first.  The error is quite vague/broad unfortunately.

Comment: If you mean our server certificate. I am not sure why this would be the issue. The problem is when connecting to an external service from the machine.

Comment: It was just a shot in the dark really, as the `Invoke-WebRequest` error can be caused by a broad range of issues.  In this case, it would be the external service cert, but if one device works, that sort of rules that out.  There's no proxy in the way that intercepts the TLS connection?

Comment: No, the VMs are in the same VirtualNetwork/subnet as well. I brought it down to the ciphersuites not being available. Because the target machine only accepts a very small amount of them.

Comment: Is the external service certificate issued by a commercial CA or private? If the latter, is its root CA in the trust-anchor store of the failing servers?

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=apil.adac.de&latest This example is using a commercial CA (GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018). But you can see in ssllabs that it only accepts very few cipher suites. E.g. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 which shows the weird invalid values on our server when retrieved via Get-TlsCipherSuites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it by using the following tool: https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/

I disabled all cypher suites, restarted the VM, re-enabled all cypher suites, and restarted once more. Works now, although I would be interested in why this happened in the first place.